# Getting data within <b> tag on Beautiful Soup or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to Extract the contents from the `<b>` tags from [this website](http://windspeed.atcouncil.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10&dec=1&latitude=33.4483771&longitude=-112.0740373&risk_category_i=105&risk_category_ii=115&risk_category_iii=120&mri_10_year=76&mri_25_year=84&mri_50_year=90&mri_100_year=96&asce_705=90&asce_793=72&zoom=4&maptype=roadmap)

I wanted to extract contents for different cities by entering in the address.

```
Query Date: Wed Aug 09 2017
Latitude: 33.4484
Longitude: -112.0740

ASCE 7-10 Windspeeds 
(3-sec peak gust in mph*):

Risk Category I: 105
Risk Category II: 115
Risk Category III-IV: 120
MRI** 10-Year: 76
MRI** 25-Year: 84
MRI** 50-Year: 90
MRI** 100-Year: 96

ASCE 7-05 Windspeed:
  90 (3-sec peak gust in mph)
ASCE 7-93 Windspeed:
  72 (fastest mile in mph)
```

The code which I've tried is given below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import urllib2
import requests
import sys
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"/usr/local/share/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://windspeed.atcouncil.org/") # opening the site
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
"""//*[@id="address"]""").click() # click the radio button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="google-map-address"]""").click() # clicking the textbox
cities = ['pheonix'] # city list
for city in cities:
# print (city)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="google-map-address"]""").send_keys(city) # passing cities
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="searchform"]/div[1]/div[2]/button""").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""// *[ @ id = "latt"]""")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchform"]/div[1]/div[7]/span/input').click()
    x = driver.current_url
print x


Data = {'optionCoordinate': '2','coordinate_address': cities}
page = requests.post(x, data = Data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser') 
for b_tag in soup.find_all('b'):
    print b_tag.text,b_tag.next_sibling
```

Please help me find the solution if it can be done with Selenium and Python BS4.

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Any error? Which line? Update the question with error stack trace.

Comment: Its showing "none" when i extract the contents based on <b> tags

Comment: If you look at the source for the web page you linked, you'll see the `<b>` tags are created with javascript. That's why BS4 can't find them. You probably need to use Selenium to load the page, rather than using `requests`. (I don't know much about Selenium, so I can't tell you how to actually do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract this data simply using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd

br = wd.Chrome()
br.get(URL)  # use url mentioned in question
s = br.find_element_by_id('bodyContent')  #search results div
print '\n'.join(s.text.split('\n')[3:22])
```

Output:

You can process this string data as you want.

```
Query Date: Wed Aug 09 2017
Latitude: 33.4484
Longitude: -112.0740

ASCE 7-10 Windspeeds
(3-sec peak gust in mph*):

Risk Category I: 105
Risk Category II: 115
Risk Category III-IV: 120
MRI** 10-Year: 76
MRI** 25-Year: 84
MRI** 50-Year: 90
MRI** 100-Year: 96

ASCE 7-05 Windspeed:
90 (3-sec peak gust in mph)
ASCE 7-93 Windspeed:
72 (fastest mile in mph)
```

Comment: Awesome Buddy, can you please explain this line what it does , "print '\n'.join(s.text.split('\n')[3:22])"

Comment: @vishal it just removes top and bottom text  of the data which is not required. You can check the complete output by printing just `s.text`.